# Node.js: How to stream remote file through my server to the user?

Tags: node.js, stream, download

There's a large binary file at somwhere.com/noo.bin

I want to send this to the user on my web app.

I don't want to save this file on my server and then serve it, wondering if there's a way to stream the file in which my web app acts as the proxy (the file will look like mysite.com/noo.bin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I would have written exactly @LaurentPerrin's answer myself, for completeness sake I should say this:

The drawback in that method is that the request headers you are sending to `somewhere.com` are unrelated to the request headers your server got. For example: if the request sent to you has a specific value for `Accept-Language`, it is likely that (as the code stands) you are not going to specify the same value for `Accept-Value` when proxying from `somewhere.com`. Thus the resource might be returned to you (and then from you to the original requester) in the wrong language.

Or if the request to you comes in with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, the current code will get the large file *uncompressed*, and will stream it back uncompressed, when you could have saved bandwidth and time by accepting and streaming back a compressed file.

This may or may not be of relevance to you.

If there are important headers you feel you need to pass, you could either add some code to explicitly copy them from your request to the request you are sending `somewhere.com`, and then copy relevant response headers back, *or* use `node-http-proxy` at https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy.

An example for a forward proxy using node-http proxy is https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/examples/http/forward-proxy.js

Comment: not sure I quite understand the first paragraph. is there a sample code I can find illustrating this?

Comment: There is an example here: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/examples/http/forward-proxy.js. If it is the first paragraph you don't understand, I'll try to edit the answer. LMK if that helps.

Answer (score 9):

Install [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request), then:

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require('request'),
    remote = 'http://somewhere.com';

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  // http://somewhere.com/noo.bin
  var remoteUrl = remote + req.url;
  request(remoteUrl).pipe(res);
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: thank you but how can i keep file name ? its changed to my url not remore file name!